# error: cannot convert 'std::string' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'char* strcpy(char*, const char*)'

Tags: c++, linux

I am getting an error in the below program:

```
error: cannot convert 'std::string' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'char*
strcpy(char*, const char*)'
```

```
std::string machine, account, passwd, dummyString; 
short sRc = FtpDestGet( BAC_REQ_DEST, machine, account, passwd, dummyString ); 
if ( sRc ) 
{ 
    fprintf( stderr, "Cannot retrieve target machine information from database, error code %ld\n", sRc ); 
    return ERROR; 
} 
strcpy( passwd, getenv(BAC_REQ_DEST));
```

Comment: When in C++ program like C++ans do and consider replacing the `fprintf` with insertions to `std::cerr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `strcpy` for C++ strings.

Do this: `passwd = getenv(BAC_REQ_DEST);`

Answer (score 3):

`strcpy()` takes a `char*` pointer to a destination buffer to write to, and a `const char*` pointer to a source buffer to read from.  But you are passing in a `std::string` object where the `char*` target buffer is expected.  `std::string` does not implicitly convert to `char*`, hence the error.

You don't need `strcpy()` to assign a `(const) char*` to a `std::string`.  `std::string` has an `operator=` for that purpose, eg:

```
passwd = getenv(BAC_REQ_DEST);
```

Also, you should be using `std::cerr` instead of `fprintf(stderr)`:

```
std::cerr << "Cannot retrieve target machine information from database, error code " << sRc << "\n";
```

You are working in C++, not in C, so use C++ idioms.